# Plot_ly height not scaling to 100% of fluidrow in Rshiny App

Tags: shiny, plotly, fluid-layout

I have an R shiny app and I am trying to display four plot_ly guage plots in them but I seem to have some stubborn space underneath each plot which I cannot work out how to get rid of. The have white space which extends below the fluid row height.

This is the code. I have tried fixing the height at 100% in various places but they all seem to include space below the plot. ideally I would like the guage to take up 100% of the height of the fluid row and the fluid row not to have a defined height at all so it scales with the window, but whatever I seem to try it stays with a space below it which is visiable if I colour everything grey.

This is the relevant code:

```
main_content_MATDetail <- mainPanel(
 
  fluidRow(
    style = "background-color: #f0f0f0; height:200px",
    column(3, plotlyOutput("OAGuage", height="100%") %>% withSpinner(color = "#12436D")),
    column(3, plotlyOutput("UAGuage") %>% withSpinner(color = "#12436D")),
    column(3, plotlyOutput("AAGuage") %>% withSpinner(color = "#12436D")),
    column(3, plotlyOutput("PAGuage") %>% withSpinner(color = "#12436D"))
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
 tabsetPanel(
   id = "main_tabs",
     tabPanel("Details ",
            titlePanel(div("Details", style = "font-size:18px;")),
            
             main_content_MATDetail
               ))
 
) #end of fluid page

server <- function(input, output, session){
 
    count_more<-9
    count_less<-17
    denominator<-(count_more+count_less)
    prop_better <- (100 * count_less/denominator)
    
    output$OAGuage <- renderPlotly({
        
        fig <- plot_ly(
            domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
            value = prop_better,
            title = list(text = "A"),
            type = "indicator",
              gauge = list(
               
                bar = list(
                    color = case_when(
                        prop_better >= 75 ~ "green",
                        prop_better >= 50 & prop_better < 75 ~ "orange",
                        TRUE ~ "red"
                    )
                ),
                axis = list(range = list(0, 100),
                            tickvals = c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100),
                            ticktext = c("0", "25", "50", "75", "100"))
            ),
            mode = "gauge+number" 
        ) 
        
        fig <- fig %>%
            layout(
                margin = list(l=0,r=0),
                paper_bgcolor = "#f0f0f0",
                font = list(color = "darkblue", family = "Arial"))
        
    })
    
    output$AAGuage <- renderPlotly({
         fig <- plot_ly(
            domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
            value = prop_better,
            title = list(text = "B"),
            type = "indicator",
            color="black",
            # plot_bgcolor = "#f0f0f0",
            gauge = list(
                # bar = list(color = "darkblue"),
                # bgcolor = "#f0f0f0",
                bar = list(
                    color = case_when(
                        prop_better >= 75 ~ "green",
                        prop_better >= 50 & prop_better < 75 ~ "orange",
                        TRUE ~ "red"
                    )
                ),
                axis = list(range = list(0, 100),
                            tickvals = c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100),
                            ticktext = c("0", "25", "50", "75", "100"))
            ),
            mode = "gauge+number" 
        ) 
        
        fig <- fig %>%
            layout(
                margin = list(l=0,r=0),
                height="100%",
                paper_bgcolor = "#f0f0f0",
                font = list(color = "darkblue", family = "Arial"))
        
    })
    
    output$UAGuage <- renderPlotly({
        fig <- plot_ly(
            domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
            value = prop_better,
            title = list(text = "C"),
            type = "indicator",
            color="black",
            # plot_bgcolor = "#f0f0f0",
            gauge = list(
                # bar = list(color = "darkblue"),
                # bgcolor = "#f0f0f0",
                bar = list(
                    color = case_when(
                        prop_better >= 75 ~ "green",
                        prop_better >= 50 & prop_better < 75 ~ "orange",
                        TRUE ~ "red"
                    )
                ),
                axis = list(range = list(0, 100),
                            tickvals = c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100),
                            ticktext = c("0", "25", "50", "75", "100"))
            ),
            mode = "gauge+number"
        ) 
        
        fig <- fig %>%
            layout(
                margin = list(l=0,r=0),
                paper_bgcolor = "#f0f0f0",
                font = list(color = "darkblue", family = "Arial"))
        
    })
    
    output$PAGuage <- renderPlotly({
        fig <- plot_ly(
            domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
            value = prop_better,
            title = list(text = "D"),
            type = "indicator",
            color="black",
     
            gauge = list(
               
                bar = list(
                    color = case_when(
                        prop_better >= 75 ~ "green",
                        prop_better >= 50 & prop_better < 75 ~ "orange",
                        TRUE ~ "red"
                    )
                ),
                axis = list(range = list(0, 100),
                            tickvals = c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100),
                            ticktext = c("0", "25", "50", "75", "100"))
            ),
            mode = "gauge+number" 
        ) 
        
        fig <- fig %>%
            layout(
                margin = list(l=0,r=0),
                paper_bgcolor = "#f0f0f0",
                font = list(color = "darkblue", family = "Arial"))
        
    })
}


##################################SHINY APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help would be gratefully receieved.

Comment: If you have extra space below your plots, you can use CSS to adjust the margins of your columns, like this `column(3, style = "margin-bottom: -30px;", ...)`. Try this and check if it gets rid of the extra space.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a scalable fluid row height, you have to use the `vh` CSS unit (percentage of the height of the viewport). Then you can use `height="100%"` in `plotlyOutput`. But there are other containers of the `plotlyOutput`s: the column and the div for the spinner, you have to set their height to 100% as well, and for the div, you need to resort to CSS.

```r
main_content_MATDetail <- mainPanel(
  
  fluidRow(
    style = "background-color: #f0f0f0; height: 40vh;",
    column(
      3, 
      style = "height: 100%;",
      plotlyOutput("OAGuage", height = "100%") %>% 
        withSpinner(color = "#12436D")
    ),
    column(
      3, 
      style = "height: 100%;",
      plotlyOutput("UAGuage", height = "100%") %>% 
        withSpinner(color = "#12436D")
    ),
    column(
      3, 
      style = "height: 100%;",
      plotlyOutput("AAGuage", height = "100%") %>% 
        withSpinner(color = "#12436D")
    ),
    column(
      3, 
      style = "height: 100%;",
      plotlyOutput("PAGuage", height = "100%") %>% 
        withSpinner(color = "#12436D")
    )
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".shiny-spinner-output-container {height: 100%}"))
  ),
  ......
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, a combination of both these answers together fixed my plot perfectly thank you.